# ¿Es posible hacer una ventana emergente (como las de tkinter o matplotlib) sin usar librerias en python?

Tags: python, librería

Eh visto que las personas hacen programas y se despliega una ventana aparte cuando es ejecutado.
¿Cómo se crean esas ventanas? es alguna funcion ya integrada en python?, es decir que cada persona pueda crear esas ventanas sin necesidad de importar nada
¿Es posible repricarlo? si lo es como se haría, si la respuesta es no porque no es posible?

Answer (score 1):

### Respuesta corta

No, no puedes crear ventanas sin librerías en Python.

---

### Respuesta larga

La creación de ventanas depende del sistema operativo. En la [documentación de Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window) puedes encontrar este ejemplo en C:

```c
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
    
        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    
        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );
    
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Puedes transcribir el código a Python con la ayuda de [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), que es una librería. Si verdaderamente quieres crear una ventana sin librerías, probablemente tengas que programar en un lenguaje de bajo nivel.

Y eso es solo el comienzo.

Las librerías existen para facilitarnos la vida. ¿Realmente no quieres utilizar ninguna?

Comment: Bueno no es que realmente no quiera usar alguna es que me llama la atención el saber como funcionan esas librerias y como las hacen, y muchas gracias por la respuesta amigo.

Comment: @Asada recuerda que hay muchas librerías para elegir. Si pretendes hacer juegos puedes utilizar SDL y Dear IMGUI para la interfaz.

Comment: @Asada tkinter es solo un intermediario entre tcl y Python. Tcl es el que trabaja con la interfáz grafica. Y librerías como pyqt se comunican con una librería del lenguaje c (sobre el que está hecho el interprete de Python) llamada qt. Como te dijeron, no hay una forma directa con built-ins de Python. Por cierto, te recomiendo que orientes tu publicación a la pregunta real, de esa manera, nos ahorramos confusiones y respuestas que no responden la duda.